# HEREDOC Returning unexpected end

Tags: php, heredoc

The following snippet is causing an

> "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs3/nettuts/PHP/PDO for Database Access/htdocs/view_users02.php on line 39"

I've looked around the site and google but didn't find an exact solution.

```
  foreach($DBH->query($sql) as $row){

        $output = "<tr><td align='left'>" . $row["name"] . "</td><td align='left'>" . $row["dr"] . "</td></tr>";


            // echo '<tr><td align="left">' . $row['name'] . '</td><td align="left">' . $row['dr'] . '</td></tr>';
     echo <<<EOT
            $output
    EOT;
```

---

**Complete Script**

```
<?php 
$page_title = 'View the Current Users';
include ('includes/header.html');

// Page header:
echo '<h1>Registered Users</h1>';

require_once ('../mysql_pdo_connect.php'); // Connect to the db.

// Make the query:

$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(last_name, ', ', first_name) AS name, DATE_FORMAT(registration_date, '%M %d, %Y') AS dr FROM users ORDER BY registration_date ASC";   

    // Table header.
    echo <<<EOT
    <table align='center' cellspacing='3' cellpadding='3' width='75%'>
    <tr><td align='left'><b>Name</b></td><td align='left'><b>Date Registered</b></td></tr>
EOT;


foreach($DBH->query($sql) as $row){

    $output = "<tr><td align='left'>" . $row["name"] . "</td><td align='left'>" . $row["dr"] . "</td></tr>";


        // echo '<tr><td align="left">' . $row['name'] . '</td><td align="left">' . $row['dr'] . '</td></tr>';
 echo <<<EOT
        $output
EOT;         

        }

    echo '</table>'; // Close the table.
    $DBH = null;


include ('includes/footer.html');
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a whole bunch of spaces (9 to be exact) after the `EOT;` in the loop.

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

> ... there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon ...

Why are you wrapping the `$output` variable inside a HEREDOC string? I'd just change the loop to

```
printf('<tr><td align="left">%s</td><td align="left">%s</td></tr>',
       htmlspecialchars($row["name"]),
       htmlspecialchars($row["dr"]));
```

or even better, use [PHP's alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).