# My PHP Document says it has an unexpected ending

Tags: php

```
<?php
require('config.php');

if(isset($_post['submit'])){

//Perform Verification
$email1 = $_POST['email1'];
$email2 = $_POST['email2'];

if($email1 == email2) {
    $firstName = mysql_escape_string($_POST['firstName']);
    $lastName = mysql_escape_string($_POST['lastName']);
    $username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $email1 = mysql_escape_string($email1);
    $email2 = mysql_escape_string($email2);
    $phone = mysql_escape_string($_POST['phone']);


    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `websiteAccount` WHERE `username`           = '$username'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    echo "Sorry, that usename is already in use.";
        exit();
    }

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `websiteAccount` (`id`, `firstName`,   `lastName`, `username` `email`, `phone`) VALUES (NULL, '$firstName', '$lastName', '$username', '$email1', '$phone')");


 }else{ 
    echo "Emails do not match";
 }
     }else{
 $form = <<<EOT
 <form action="register.php" method="post">
 First Name:<br><input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
 Last Name:<br><input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
 Username:<br><input type="text" name="username"><br>
 Email:<br><input type="text" name="email1"><br>
 Confirm Email:<br><input type="text" name="email2"><br>
 Phone:<br><input type="text" name="phone"><br>
 <inpu type="submit" value="Register" name="submit">
 </form>


 EOT;

echo $form;
}
?>
```

When I tried to open this code in my PHP Server:
I received a message saying 
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Web/register.php on line 48**

Comment: May I know, `$form = <<<EOT`. What is that? Where is the `;` symbol for ending a line of code?

Comment: Is the `EOT;` all the way to the left with no spaces in front?

Comment: @HendryTanaka, the <<<EOT is PHP heredoc string syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061312/heredoc-returning-unexpected-end

Comment: @yitwail, Thanks. I'm new in PHP

Comment: @HendryTanaka, you're welcome. Not everyone uses it, in part because the matching `EOT;` has to be in column one, as sectus points out in his answer, so that it can mess up code indentation.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

> Warning
>
> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier
>   must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;).

```
 EOT;
^
```

You need to remove this extra space.